# Refer to two articles of one group of authors

Tags: citing, natbib

Please consider the following sample codes:

```
\documentclass[‎‎a4paper,11pt]{article}‎

‎\usepackage[round]{natbib}‎

    \begin{document}
    \section{Introduction}
    \citet{Lin:1992} and \citet{Lin:1993} studied the projection properties of Plackett-Burman designs.

    \begin{‎thebibliography}‎

    \bibitem[Lin and Draper (1992)]{Lin:1992}‎
    Lin, D. K. J. and Draper, N. R. (1992). Projection properties of Plackett and Burman designs.
    \textit{Technometrics} \textbf{34}, 423--428. ‎

    \bibitem[Lin and Draper (1993)]{Lin:1993}‎
    ‎Lin, D. K. J. and Draper, N. R. (1993). Generating alias relationships for two-level Plackett
    and Burman designs. \textit{Comput. Statist. Data Anal.} \textbf{15}, 147--157.

    \end{thebibliography} 
    \end{document}
```

How can I rewrite the sentence in the article as below?

"Lin and Draper (1992, 1993) studied the projection properties of Plackett-Burman designs."

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should format properly the optional argument to `\bibitem` (no space between the names and the year). However, it would be better to use BibTeX.

Then you can combine `\citeauthor` and `\citeyear`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}

\citeauthor{Lin:1992} (\citeyear{Lin:1992} and \citeyear{Lin:1993})
studied the projection properties of Plackett-Burman designs.

\begin{thebibliography}{}

\bibitem[Lin and Draper(1992)]{Lin:1992}
Lin, D. K. J. and Draper, N. R. (1992). Projection properties of
Plackett and Burman designs.
\textit{Technometrics} \textbf{34}, 423--428.  

\bibitem[Lin and Draper(1993)]{Lin:1993}
Lin, D. K. J. and Draper, N. R. (1993). Generating alias
relationships for two-level Plackett and Burman designs.
\textit{Comput. Statist. Data Anal.} \textbf{15}, 147--157.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]